# Ada - compiler warning about "mod 64" type definition

Tags: types, syntax, ada

I require a modular integer type with valid values between 0 and 63 inclusive.  Such as...

```
type Mix_Byte is mod 64;
```

This does compile and work as expected but the compiler helpfully draws my attention to a possible oversight on my part...

```
warning: 2 ** 64 may have been intended here
```

As it happens I do not intend that at all, but it's nice to know the compiler is on the look out :)

It only seems to give this warning for values 32 or 64, but not 8, 16 or 128.  I understand that 32 and 64 are common integer sizes and in those cases `2 ** n` would make sense.

How do I silence this specific compiler warning for this particular instance (I want to allow it globally throughout my project in case I make a genuine mistake elsewhere).

I presume I can articulate the code differently in order to be more precise with my meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some additional background info (apart from egilhh's answer): the check is done in `freeze.adb` (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/ada/freeze.adb?view=markup#l2456)). The warning can be enabled/disabled using `-gnatw.m/.M.` (see output of `gnatmake --help`). You can temporarily disable the warning by using the `Warnings` pragma (see also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Warnings.html) and [here](https://www.adacore.com/gems/ada-gem-18)):

**main.adb**

```
procedure Main is

   pragma Warnings (Off, "*may have been intended here");
   type Mix_Byte_1 is mod 64;
   pragma Warnings (On, "*may have been intended here");

   type Mix_Byte_2 is mod 64;   --  Line 7

begin
   null;
end Main;
```

**output** (gnat)

```
$ gcc -c main.adb
main.adb:7:27: warning: 2 ** 64 may have been intended here
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to write it as a power of two:

```
type Mix_Byte is mod 2**6;
```

Edit:

Alternatively, (based on more info in your comment)
you can use a named number as the modulus:

```
Modulus : constant := 64;
type Mix_Byte is mod Modulus;
```

Comment: Amusingly, the project I'm working on is derived from the "Mix" computer from Knuth's book TAOCP.  In which a byte has an unspecified size and the implementer is free to choose whatever size is convenient where Byte_Max is anywhere between 63 and 100.  Your answer works for the question as it was originally stated.  I was hoping there was a way to articulate this without using the `2**` notation, but only for some arcane reason.

Comment: Sorry for removing the "accept" from this answer and giving it to @DeeDee instead.  As the question was written "How do I silence this specific compiler warning for..." DeeDee's answer is dead-on.  I like your `2 ** 6` solution better for my particular needs and I'll be using it in my project, many thanks.